# Catalogo con card para mostras mas info

Tags: angular6, angular7

Buenas estoy haciendo un catalogo que al dar click muestre un card con más info.
El problema viene que al darle click se abre todas las cards del catalogo.

Lo que quiero es que solo se muestre la card sobre la imagen que doy click.
Utilizo el ngFor el de manera que la variable *isShown* se utiliza en todos los click.
.html

```
<div class="catalogo" *ngFor="let img of imgenes">
  <img class="portada" src="{{img.cover}}" (click)="isShown = !isShown">
  <div class="collapse" [ngClass]="{ 'show': isShown }">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="" class="card-img" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
              content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inicializo el Booleano

.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
     selector: 'app-catalogo',
     templateUrl: './catalogo.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./catalogo.component.scss']
})
export class CatalogoComponent implements OnInit {

isShown = false;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Los estilos
.scss

```
.body {
    background: #29231E;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
    margin: auto;
 }

 .catalogo {
    width: 25%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de lo que quieras lograr, tienes dos opciones:

#### Se puede mostrar detalles de más de un elemento a la vez:

En este caso necesitas un *flag* para cada elemento, podrías añadirlo al él mismo:

```
<div class="catalogo" *ngFor="let img of imgenes">
  <img class="portada" src="{{img.cover}}" (click)="img.isShown = !img.isShown">
  <div class="collapse" [ngClass]="{ 'show': img.isShown }">
  ...
```

#### Sólo se puede mostrar detalles de un elemento

En este caso tienes que saber qué elemento es, por ejemplo usando el índice. En lugar de tener un *flag* booleano, guardas el elemento a mostrar:

```
<div class="catalogo" *ngFor="let img of imgenes; let i = index">
  <img class="portada" src="{{img.cover}}" (click)="show(i)">
  <div class="collapse" [ngClass]="{ 'show': toBeShown(i) }">
```

con los métodos:

```
show(i: number) {
  this.isShown = this.isShown === i ? -1 : i; //-1 si queremos ocultar con un segundo click
}

toBeShown(i: number) {
  return this.isShown === i;
}
```